# Can't you instanceOf Class ? if not how to achive that?

Tags: java

And to avoid XY question, Here is that I want achive:

```java
Class<?> clazz= Class.forName("XXXXX"); // If I'm super sure this type is MyClass

if ( clazz instanceOf MyClass.class ) {

}

// Or


switch (clazz){

case MyClass1.class:{ }
case MyClass2.class:{ }
```

None of them right, I try to this:

```java
List<MyClass1> list;

Class<?> superclass = clazz.getSuperclass();
if (superclass == MyClass1.class) {
    list.add(clazz);  // This is wrong with error
    list.add((MyClass1) clazz); // This is working but IDE warning 
}
```

Is there any elegent way to instanceOf a Class? Because cast after instanceOf is safe.

```java
if ( obejct instanceOf People){
    (People) object;
}
```

Comment: "And to avoid XY question, Here is that I want achive" Okay, but what *problem do you hope to solve* by doing this?

Comment: A class is not an object, instanceof is used for objects. Class equality can be checked using equality `aClass == aClass`.

Comment: There is `Class.isInstance()` and also `Class.cast()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mix up some facts.
`MyClass instance = ...` is an instance of `MyClass` with wich you could use `instanceof` and which you could add to a `List<MyClass>`.
`Class<?> clazz = ...` is also an instance but not an instance of `MyClass` but an instance of the class `Class` (which is final) so `clazz instanceof MyClass` will never return true.
And because it is *not* an instance of `MyClass` you should get a `ClassCastException` at runtime if you try to cast `clazz` to `MyClass`.

So to check the `Class` instance `clazz` you should use `Class#isAssignableFrom`

```
Class<?> clazz= Class.forName("XXXXX");
if (MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That is the elegent way with exactly want.